# Can strings and integers/floats be mixed when formatting via ostringstream

Tags: c++, printf, ostringstream

I'm trying to fully understand how to use `ostringstream` to modernize some code that uses `sprintf`. The problem is in replacing test code that generates random or sequential data.  Here's a simplified example:

```
char num[6], name[26];
sprintf(num, "%05d", i);
sprintf(name, "Customer # %d", i);
```

Leaving aside the minutia of length calculation, copying the result to the array and null-termination, the `num` conversion is straightforward:

```
ostringstream ostr;
ostr << setw(len) << setfill('0') << i;
```

For example, given `i` as 123, the result is "00123".
However, for the `name`, which is actually a mixture of a char-string and an integer, I can't figure how to replicate what `sprintf` appears to do so easily.
I tried variations of this:

```
ostr << setw(len) << left << "Customer # " << i << setfill(' ');
```

Given the same value for `i`, the result was always "Customer #               123", i.e., the integer always right justified, no matter what combination of `left`, `right` or `internal`, or the placement of the various parts. It seems the only solution (I haven't tried it yet), is to first concatenate the "Customer # " and the `i` onto a separate `ostringstream` and then insert *that* left justified to the `ostr` variable. Am I missing something?  Is there some other way?

---

Correction: as discussed in the comments, in simplifying the example I overlooked a second `sprintf` that was actually responsible for right-padding the name. So a second output to the `ostringsteam` is also needed to accomplish that.

Comment: What is the purpose of `setw`? It does not correspond to anything in the corresponding `sprintf` call.

Comment: IO modifiers like `std::setw` only apply to call to `operator<<` that immediately follows them.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I'm afraid I simplified too much. The actual code does two sprintfs for the name, one as shown and a second to pad right with spaces, i.e., something like `sprintf(name + strlen(name), "%*.s", len - strlen(name), " ");`

Comment: `ostringstream` is not handy for complex formatting, give a try on the awesome `fmt` library

Comment: Based on Sam and Brian's comments above and my finding that a second sprintf is used, I guess the desired formatting could be achieved as follows: `ostr << left << "Customer # " << i; ostr << setw(len - ostr.str().size()) << setfill(' ') << " ";`

Comment: @JoeAbbate So the second one is `sprintf(name + strlen(name), "%*.s%s", len - strlen(name), " ", name);` so that name is right justified in a string of `len` length?  If that's right we should edit the question.  I think prehistoricpenguin is right - it's not easy - if you need two sprintf lines then you need two stringstreams.  You should definitely look at the fmt library.

Comment: `i.e., the integer always right justified, no matter what combination of left, right or internal` but it is always right justified in `sprintf(name, "Customer # %d", i);` I do not understand  - why are you doing functionally different C++ code then C code? Why not `ostr << "Customer # " << i;`? `The actual code does two sprintfs for the name` Well, please do not post unrelated code then... Please include the expected output (ie. look after printing it out) for the input (ie. for `i=123`.

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah: Correction added. I've looked at {fmt} and it does look quite promising.

Comment: "How `ostringstream` does ...". It doesn't, really `ostringstream` is just an `ostream` which outputs to string, and the question would be the same for `std::cout`.

Comment: Just in case you want to see what it looks like if you do use a temporary stringstream to build the string and then use a second one to justify it: https://onlinegdb.com/BJo6pmUUu